# Making control with attached property in code behind (WPF)

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have UserControl1 and I want to create it's instance and set attached property for it in the code behind of the other UserControl2.
The other words, I have in the UserControl2:

```
<UserControl2>
  <Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</UserControl2>
```

And I want to do:

```
<UserControl2>
  <Canvas>
     <UserControl1 Canvas.Left="100" ... />
  </Canvas>
</UserControl2>
```

How can I create UserControl1 with attached property **in code behind of the UserControl2**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UserControl1 ctrl = new UserControl1();
Canvas.SetLeft(ctrl, 100);
```